# What is the function of 'i' in for loop in JavaScript when accessing arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```js
const rapperArray = ['Tupac', 'Jay-Z', 'Notorious B.I.G', 'Kendrick Lamar']

for (let i = 0; i < rapperArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(rapperArray[i]);
  if (i === 2) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log("And if you don't know, now you know.");
```

So how does `i` work in that `console.log( rapperArray[ i ] );`? I know that it accesses the elements in the array but I can't seem to get my head around how it actually functions.

Comment: It's just an index.  The 0 index is the 1st element, the 1st index is the 2nd element and so on.

Comment: But do you know how `rapperArray[0]` functions?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are really asking.

Comment: Each time the loop iterates `i`, which you established as having a starting value of `0` is incremented by one (that's what the `i++` means). Since Arrays start indexing at 0, the first time through `i` will be `0` and therefore `rapperArray[i]` will reference `rapperArray[0]` or the first item in the array (`Tupac`). The second time  through, `i` will be `1` and `rapperArray[i]` will mean `rapperArray[1]` or `Jay-Z`. This will continue as long as `i` is less than the length of the array (which is 1-based) or 4.

Comment: `i` generally denotes the current iterative row identifier in an array. `var a =['a','b']` with `a[0] == 'a', a[1] == 'b'` and so forth, with `i` being `0` then `1` in that example, `var i = 0; a[i] == 'a'; i = 1; a[i] == 'b'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `i` is a variable. In a for loop, you have the following syntax:

```
for(initialization; condition; update) {
    // for loop body
}
```

The for loop will begin by running the `initialization` portion first, which in this case declares the variable `i` with an initial value of `0`. Before each iteration of the loop, `condition` is checked and the loop body will run as long as `condition` is `true`. Then, after the loop body runs, `update` will run. In this case, the variable `i` will have its value incremented by `1`, i.e. `i++` is basically the same thing as `i += 1`.

In other words, the for loop will use every value of `i` from `0` up until `rapperArray.length - 1`. So `console.log(rapperArray[i]);` will be the same as `console.log(rapperArray[0]);` in the first iteration, `console.log(rapperArray[1]);` in the second iteration, and so on.

You can see this more clearly by running the following:

```js
const rapperArray = ['Tupac', 'Jay-Z', 'Notorious B.I.G', 'Kendrick Lamar'];

for (let i = 0; i < rapperArray.length; i++) {
  console.log('When i is ' + i + ', rapperArray[i] is ' + rapperArray[i] + '.');
}
```

Comment: Ohh, so ```i``` is being used as an index for the array in the loop. So that it prints the names... I see it now

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop header consists of three parts:

- Initial state `let i = 0`
- Condition to check if loop should continue `i < length`
- Increment per run `i++`

We start with `0`, in the beginning `i` is lower than `length`, then we up it by `1` (i++ increases i by 1), if it's still lower than length - we continue until `i` has the same value as  `length` and then we stop.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates the current iteration of the loop. For each iteration, `i` is incremented. When used to get an array item, it represents the index of the item to retrieve from the array. You can read more about indexed collections here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections

Arrays in JavaScript are zero-index based, which means the first index is always zero. And they increment from there. Arrays are ordered collections, so the item at the first index (zero) is always the same, and so on.

If you have a list on paper in front of you, you may number the lines starting with `1` and going up from there. Each item in an array is somewhat like each line on that piece of paper, only the line numbers start at zero instead of one. If you want to get line `n` from the paper, you find the line numbered `n` and there you go.